# How can i get the code coverage percentage information?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, code-coverage

I'm trying to do unit testing in swift. I have a two-class named `MyFileManager` and `SomeViewModel`

```
class MyFileManager {
    static let shared = MyFileManager()
    
    func isStored(atPath path: String) -> Bool {
        return FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path)
    }
    func readData(atPath path: String) -> Data? {
        return try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    }
}

class SomeViewModel {
    func getCachedData() -> Data? {
        let path = "xxxxx"
        
        if MyFileManager.shared.isStored(atPath: path) {
            return MyFileManager.shared.readData(atPath: path)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I've written a test code. I'm not sure whether this code will give me 100% code coverage or not. Here is the unit test

```
class LinePhoneTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        testGetCachedData()
    }

    func testGetCachedData() {
        let viewModel = SomeViewModel()
        
        let data = viewModel.getCachedData()
        XCTAssertFalse((data != nil))
        
        XCTAssertTrue((data == nil))
    }

}
```

How can I get code coverage percentage information?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I want to reach 100% code coverage for SomeViewModel Class. How can I achieve that?

Comment: does my provided test code is correct for the above class?

Comment: Not related to your question but why not simply `XCTAssertNotNil(viewModel.getCachedData())`

Comment: It looks like your test is trying to ensure that caching is working. You should name it in a way that communicates that. Perhaps: `testThatDataIsCached` (more details would be beneficial)

Comment: By the way, the "check then act" pattern is pretty unfixably broken. Anytime you check and act in two separate steps without a synchronization mechanism, you have a possibility for bugs. In this case, it's possible that between the time that you check `.isStored(atPath: path)` and then react by doing `.readData(atPath: path)`, something else could have deleted the file from under your nose. You should just attempt the read. If the file doesn't exist, just catch the error and then handle that case.

Comment: You can never reach 100% code coverage and it's pointless to try. That's one of the most common mistakes of beginner unit testers. Test what you think should be tested. Use coverage as a hint what is not tested and look whether it should be tested but don't try for full coverage. There are many lines that cannot be even tested, e.g. `fatalError`. Also, there are many error states that just cannot be simulated using a unit test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are things you can do to monitor code coverage to help you write your tests.

Turn on the Code Coverage setting in your scheme:

[image]

Turn on this menu item:

[image]

And then in your source files you'll see a gutter in the corner: which will show you a number indicating the number of tests that exercise this line, and in red, the lines that have not been exercised.

[image]

And you can see the percentage under Code Coverage in your build results:

[image]

With these tools you can write tests to exercises the code paths you need to get to 100%, or you can make a judgement as to whether the missed tests are important or not.